# Content in a horizontal flexbox (accordion) overflowing

Tags: css, html, accordion, flexbox

I have a problem with a flexbox (accordion). In the example feedled below I have groups of contents, with each group having a cell in a horizontal flexbox and inside each cell the contents pertaining to each group.

Live example & code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesanjos/KaUhK/2/).

The problem is that when the content of a group is too big, it overflows the flexbox and i can't come up with a solution for this.

Comment: Did you try giving a fixed height and overflow: auto to the ul element?

Comment: Not tested that yet David, i will give it a try nevertheless Aaron's solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Although a little late, I have just wrote an article that might help you: http://www.webdeveasy.com/flexbox-accordion/

Comment: Great work @Naor, thanks! Altough sadly I won't be able to test it since i've dropped that project long ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.box`'s `height` declaration to `min-height`. I've forked your jsFiddle with the result: http://jsfiddle.net/MzFhN/1/